# Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have no idea why i got such a problem when I wrote this kotlin code

```
Log.d(TAG, msg:"onCreate called. Score is :$score")
```

Comment: Remove "msg:" -> Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called. Score is :$score")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you were trying to use named arguments, judging my `msg` being the name of the second argument in `Log.d`, and it matching in your code. You do, however, have two problems:

- Named arguments only works with all-Kotlin code. If the function is in Java, you can't use it
- Named arguments use `=`, not `:`

As in you could do:

```
data class SomeClass(val x: String, val y: String)
fun someFunction(){
    SomeClass(y = "y", x = "x")
}
```

But you can't do it for `Log.d`, because it's not a Kotlin function. For reference, this is the appropriate syntax:

```
Log.d(TAG, msg="onCreate called. Score is :$score")
```

But it won't compile, because `Named arguments are not allowed for non-Kotlin functions`. So remove it. You can't use named arguments with that method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "msg:"

```
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called. Score is :$score")
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use Log.d(TAG, "msg:onCreate called. Score is :$score")